# EditText is not showing in the preview screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a strange problem with my android studio IDE. Whenever I'm taking the EditText, its preview is not showing in the preview screen of android studio. I tried with different layouts but it doesn't work. And the problem is only with my laptop it's running completely fine on my friend's laptop. I tried literally everything like changing the color, uninstalling the whole android studio but nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: EditText Preview Image]

Comment: this is happening only for edittext ?

Comment: there might be loading of preview. di d you check with real device ?

Comment: Yeah, @Manikandan  I Checked it with real data and the problem is with my previous project also. I had recently made a project and it was working fine. But now when I opened that project it also has the same problem.

Comment: Yes. The problem is only with EditText  @dinkar_kumar

Comment: @iamdhvalparmar..so you telling you can able to see edit text in real device  right ? the problem is not showing edit text in preview androd studio right ? if yes means try to invalid restart in android studio

Comment: @Manikandan Yes I'm able to see it in real device. I tried everything man I even reinstalled the whole android studio.

Comment: I'm also faced this issue. But I don't Know How its working now in android studio.,.Cool

Comment: @Manikandan I'm working on a crucial project and this is happening with me.

Comment: I suggest you replace that EditText with `TextInputLayout + TextInputEditText`  as described in the [material design](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields) specs. Then ensure you have the correct theme, and also set the same theme in the visual editor.

Comment: Okay, @MartinMarconcini I will try.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I tried but it's not working either.

Comment: did you try setting some background to see whether even then you are able to render it in preview or not?

Comment: Yes, I tried bro. @dinkar_kumar

Comment: `android:background="#E1E0E0"` add this in your EditText.

Comment: The problem is with the IDE not with your code above the design Android 30 is selected and on right red error is shown pick Android 21 and the error gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried all the answers which I received but nothing works then finally now I'm using the alternative of `EditText` which is `TextInputEditText` which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your  IDE is in dark mode

check right theme also hier

[image]

(by switch to Dark mode remove `android:textColor="@color/black"` from `EditText`)

With line `tools:context=".MainActivity"` your preview in `Android Studio` takes all settings, you made in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`. Do you change color of `EditText` in runtime?

Although, in case you use `LinearLayout` set `android:orientation="vertical"` or `horizontal` to `LinearLayout`

Comment: It's not working. My IDE is already in 'Not Night' mode and I had used `android:orientation="vertical"` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @iamdhavalparmar, Have you tried to change to dark? Have you maked something in themes? try to remove `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Comment: I had not changed anything in theme file, I also made a new project but the EditText doesn't show up. When I turned it in the dark mode just the background color of the screen turns black . And also tried by removing `tools:context=".MainActivity`. Then problem is with IDE not with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Layout Rendering Engine

[image]

I once had this issue where some components display properly or nothing displays at all.. Once I disabled this experimental feature, there were no issues.. Try this once..